# How to create an array with limits for all values contained in another list

Tags: python, arrays, range

I am searching for a fast way to create an array of lower and upper limits for each value contained another array. Please have a look at the pseudo code below:

```
A=[23.4,3434.2,43535]
#Take each element in A and create B containing upper and lower limit:
B=[A[0]-limit,A[0]+limit, ....]
```

I am not sure if a nested list is needed. What I would like to do in greater scheme of things is to compare this limits to a larger array **C** and find *all* values in **A** within the limits defined in **B**. The problem for me is that the values in  **A** are a pattern but do not necessarily match the values in **C** without taking the limits into account. Maybe numpy or pandas are useful here?

EDIT:

This is what i would like to use later on. However, if A is used directly, there will be no matches, since no error limits are defined.

```
numpy.where(pandas.Index(pandas.unique(B)).get_indexer(C) >= 0)[0]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> limit = 100
>>> A = [23.4,3434.2,43535]
>>> B = [(a-limit, a+limit) for a in A]
>>> B
[(-76.6, 123.4), (3334.2, 3534.2), (43435, 43635)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
B=[a+s*limit for a in A for s in [-1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This works but I prefer to go with @tobias_k solution for the tuple character of the output.

Comment: No problem, Cheers :)